# Autorun python script save output to txt file raspberry pi

Tags: python, output, boot, autorun

I have a issue with my raspberry pi that starts up a python script.How do I save the printed output to a file when it is running on boot? I found script below on the internet but it doesn't seem to write the printed text,it creates the file but the content is empty.

```
sudo python /home/pi/python.py > /home/pi/output.log
```

Comment: is the code from your python file even producing any output? if you're simply redirecting the output of a script which just runs something it won't write anything to a log file

Comment: when i run my python file from idle it write the output in txt file but when running on boot content in text file is empty. python file contain infinite while loop that print the input of gpio pin.

Comment: in my python file i use gpio pin as input and print the input given to gpio pin and certain calculation depend on the input in gpio pin when i run my python file from idle it write the input given to gpio pin and the final calculated value in txt file but when running on boot content in text file is empty.

Comment: You're only printing standard out, not standard error. The script could be failing

Comment: i am new to raspberry pi and python so don't have much idea about it. so how could i write the output.

Answer (score 2):

It does write its output to the file but you cannot see it until the python file has finished executing due to buffer never flushed.

If you change the output to a file within your python script you can periodicity call flush in your code to push the output through to the file as and when you wish, something like this.

```py
    import sys
    import time
    outputFile = "output.txt";
    with open(outputFile, "w+") as sys.stdout:
        while True:
            print("some output")
            sys.stdout.flush() # force buffer content out to file
            time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds
```

if you want to set the output back to the terminal, you may want to save a reference to the original stdout like this

```
    import time
    outputFile = "output.txt";
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    with open(outputFile, "w+") as sys.stdout:
        print("some output in file")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
    print("back in terminal")
```